# How to set the width of all the tool-tips in SmartGWT applicaion globally?

Tags: java, css, gwt, tooltip, smartgwt

I have lots of tool-tips in my SmartGWT application and now I want to change the width of each tool-tip without setting width of each individual tool-tip that is most tedious task.

I can set the width of tool-tip in SmartGWT using [Canvas#setHoverWidth()](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/Canvas.html#setHoverWidth%28java.lang.Integer%29) but my concern is to apply this setting globally applicable for whole application.

**Is there any way in SmartGWT to specify the tool-tip width globally applicable for whole application using CSS or JAVA code?**

For sample code have a look at [Hovers Tooltips Sample (Smart GWT)](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/HoversTooltipsSampleSmartGWT.htm).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I got the style name that is applied on all the tool-tips.

> SmartGWT have a concept of [Skinning](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/docs/Skinning.html) that is the process of modifying Smart GWT's default look and feel to match the desired look and feel for your application.

A "skin" consists of:

- a single CSS stylesheet containing all CSS styles used by Smart GWT components (skin_styles.css)
- a single JavaScript file that sets component defaults (load_skin.js)
- a directory tree of images organized by component

---

I found the style `canvasHover` in `skin_styles.css` that is used for hovering on `Canvas`.

I just added `min-width: 135px;` that changed the width of all the tool-tips globally in the application. By default it's `100px`.

```
/* hover canvas  */
.canvasHover,.gridHover,.formHover {
    background-color: #fdfdd3;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    color: black;
    font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 5px;
    min-width: 135px;
}
```

Thanks a lot for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about SmartGWT works, but for this kind of dirty things if those elements are attached to the DOM, I'd use GQuery.

Something like:

```
GQuery.$("#yourTooltipId or .yourTooltipClass", RootPanel.get()).each(new Function() { public void f(Element e){
  GQuery.$(e).width(30);
}});
```

Instead of `RootPanel.get()`, you can use other **scope** if for any reason you have all the tool-tips under the same view.

Comment: I have to do it for each `yourTooltipId`?

Comment: No, if see the code, you can notice "each", that means if all the tooltips share the same class or id, all of them are matched, and for each one is executed the f Function.

Comment: I am not using `JQuery` in my project. Can you suggest equivalent `JavaScript` code?

Comment: That is the point. It is not JQuery, is GQuery :D see https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/

Comment: Sorry I haven't heard `GQuery` before. Let me try.

Comment: No worries! Check Selectors (like jQuery), Ajax and Promises (under my opinion those are the most useful parts).